# Wiring up Autofac in MonoGame

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, monogame

I'm attempting to wire up Autofac v4.6.2 in MonoGame v3.6.

This is what I have in my program.cs

```
public static class Program
{
    private static IContainer Container { get; set; }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<TheGame>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
        builder.RegisterType<GraphicsDeviceManager>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
        builder.RegisterType<GraphicsAdapter>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<GraphicsDevice>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<GraphicsProfile>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.Register((c, p) => GraphicsProfile.HiDef).As<GraphicsProfile>();
        builder.RegisterType<PresentationParameters>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<EditorCamera>().As<ICamera>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        Container = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var game = Container.Resolve<TheGame>();
            game.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

What's happening is when I run this, upon attempting to resolve `TheGame`, a null reference exception is thrown in the `GraphicsDevice` class as the `GraphicsAdapter` is null.

Here is the `GraphicsDevice` class constructor:

```
public GraphicsDevice(GraphicsAdapter adapter, GraphicsProfile graphicsProfile, PresentationParameters presentationParameters);
```

The `GraphicsAdapter` class constructor:

```
public GraphicsAdapter();
```

What am I missing? If someone could help me out here that would be greatly appreciated!

(Running VS2017 Community)

EDIT:

The game class which all my magic goes into looks like this:
    public class TheGame : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

```
    // Lots of members declared

    internal TheGame()
    {
        // Be default this is public, but hidden for autofac integration
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    public TheGame(ICamera camera, GraphicsDeviceManager graphicsDeviceManager)
    {
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics = graphicsDeviceManager;
        this.camera = camera;
    }

    // ...
```

`GraphicsDevice` is a Property in `GraphicsDeviceManager`

```
 public class GraphicsDeviceManager : IGraphicsDeviceService, IDisposable, IGraphicsDeviceManager
{
    public static readonly int DefaultBackBufferWidth;
    public static readonly int DefaultBackBufferHeight;

    public GraphicsDeviceManager(Game game);

    ~GraphicsDeviceManager();

    // ....

    public bool HardwareModeSwitch { get; set; }
    public GraphicsDevice GraphicsDevice { get; }
    public bool IsFullScreen { get; set; }
    public GraphicsProfile GraphicsProfile { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler<PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs> PreparingDeviceSettings;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Where is the graphicsdevice called? Is it able to reach the GraphicsAdapter?

Comment: `graphicsDevice` is called within `GraphicsDeviceManager`, which is used in the Game class (the class which we inherit to make our game).

Comment: Are you intentionally registering two different `GraphicsProfile` services? (The type itself, then a lambda after that.) Do you need to resolve `IEnumerable<GraphicsProfile>` for anything? Might be confusing if not.

Comment: What is the exception exactly? Can u show us the stacktrace?